# Add submenu using controls/toolbox items or any other way?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a menu with  4  menu items. The 4th menu item is to be having upto 3 sub-menu items.

Im working in VS2010.I'm looking for adding a submenu to an already existing menu in VS 2010. Is there a way I can do it using controls/toolbox items or in any other alternative  in VS?